# Parsing a date with antlr

Tags: antlr, grammar

I am trying to parse the following date in antlr:

'2014-01-01'

with this grammar:

```
fragment DIGITX: '0'..'9';
fecha:  '\'' DIGITX DIGITX DIGITX DIGITX '-' DIGITX DIGITX '-' DIGITX DIGITX '\'' ;
```

My problem is that it never parses it. Why is it?

Thanks.

Comment: ... probably because there are other rules that prevent this one from matching. Without more details we cannot help you. What is the exact error message? Have you tried with a minimal grammar?

Comment: yeah you were right, i had another rule that also parsed the same thing. Thank you